# How to remove unwanted values in data when reading csv file

Tags: pandas, csv, data-processing

Reading Pina_Indian_Diabities.csv some of the values are strings, something like this
+AC0-5.4128147485

```
734                    2
735                    4
736                    0
737                    8
738    +AC0-5.4128147485
739                    1
740                  NaN
741                    3
742                    1
743                    9
744                   13
745                   12
746                    1
747                    1
```

like in row 738, there re such values in other rows and columns as well.

How can I drop them?

Comment: [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` replaces anything non-numeric with NaN. What about row 740, does that need to remain or not?

Comment: The code would be `df['column_name'] = pd.to_numeric(df['column_name'], errors='coerce')``

Comment: Thanks that worked. Just another doubt that is there any way I can apply this operation on all the columns at once?